# Estimating test error from $X^TX$ and $X^Ty$

Tags: regression, linear, time-complexity

Suppose we've got a dataset with a very large number of samples (say, billions), and a smaller number of features (say, hundreds). To calculate the coefficients of a single a ridge regression model, all we need are $X_{train}^TX_{train}$ and $X_{train}^Ty_{train}$, which are small and can fit in memory.

However, it seems like to evaluate those models on the test set, no corresponding approach is possible, and that it's necessary to sequentially load the entire test set.

My question is, is there a way to evaluate a linear model using just $X_{test}^TX_{test}$ and $X_{test}^Ty_{test}$ ?